# How to create bottom Navigation bar like Material.io

Tags: android, material-design, bottomnavigationview, android-bottom-nav-view, android-bottomnavigationview

I have been trying to configure the bottom navigation bar to looks like the material.io,

I checked https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-navigation-view/
and 
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView

I am out of luck, and looks like they may not use BottomNavigationView.calss to create this

[image]

https://material.io/design/environment/surfaces.html#attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement that bottom app bar on Android with `BottomAppBar` from `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`.
Here is the reference guide :https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-app-bar/

There is a "Develop" section on material.io that teaches you how to use libraries to use each component on all platforms. At the moment, most components are not implemented on Android, but hopefully `BottomAppBar` is already available !

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought it was BottomNavigationView, I didn't know there bottom-app-bar is a thing before!